# Уведомление без звука

Tags: android, уведомления

Есть несколько уведомлений с разными ид , и звуки у всех разные. Уведомления приходят поочередно, каждые 5 минут. Как мне сделать например при isMuted == true звуки всех уведомлений отключались? Где создается chanel прописал channel.setSound(null, null); результата 0.  Как мне переключить этот режим в коде? Какой класс и метод отвечает за эту функцию?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После долгого поиска решения этой задачи, решил остановиться на этом варианте.

```
 Uri[] ringSounds;

   private Uri listUriSounds(int a) {
        if (IntervalSharedPref.getIsMutedSound("ismuted")) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> maps : mMap.entrySet()) {
                ringSounds[0] =
                        Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.myapplication/" + R.raw.sv);
                ringSounds[1] =
                        Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.myapplication/" + R.raw.sb);
                ringSounds[2] =

       ...........                 

            }
        } else if (!IntervalSharedPref.getIsMutedSound("ismuted")){
            for (int i=0;i<ringSounds.length; i++){
                ringSounds[i] = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.nameapp/" + R.raw.sound5);
            }
        }

        return ringSounds[a];
    }


                        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                                new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, CHANNEL_ID)
                                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                        .setContentTitle("TITLE")
                                        .setContentText("TEXT")                                      .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MIN).setSound(listUriSounds(1))
                                        .setAutoCancel(true);
                        Notification notification = builder.build();
                        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: Попробуйте установить минимальный приоритет для уведомления. Судя по доке, это должно отключить звук: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels.html#importance

Comment: Не первый раз выручаешь) Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйта) Вы можете даже это в ответ написать (с примером кода) - наверняка кому-то ещё пригодится)

Comment: Не уверен, что кому-то понравится мой подход к решению), но все таки добавлю потом.

Comment: Походу я поторопился. Как бы я не менял NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE... в канале,  ничего не меняется... Уведомления так и приходят  со звуком ,в котором я указываю в ```NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, CHANNEL_ID).setSound(" ")```   Знаете ли , есть ли другой способ?

Comment: Странно , что если указать IMPORTANCE_MIN вообще результата не видно.  Хоть и написано "No sound and does not appear in the status bar"

Comment: Других идей у меня нет. Возможно это вообще нельзя сделать. В качестве последней меры попробуйте, например, создать звуковой файл с тишиной и его назначать в качестве звука для уведомления)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels.html#UpdateChannel - вот тут говорится что после создания канала изменять его настройки программно нельзя, можно только открыть окно настроек канала и юзер пусть крутит их сам. К слову, канал создаётся единожды и существует пока существует приложение, все последующие вызовы `createNotificationChannel` с тем же id ничего не дают, кроме возможности изменить имя-фамилию, группу и понизить важность, остальное игнорируется.

Answer (score 2):

У меня сработало следующее:
Я добавил в notification builder ".setSilent(true)".
Пример:

```
        builder
            .setContentTitle(description.getTitle())
            .setContentText(description.getSubtitle())
            .setSubText(description.getDescription())
            .setLargeIcon(description.getIconBitmap())
            .setNumber (12)
            .setSilent(true)
            .setContentIntent(controller.getSessionActivity())
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    return builder;
```